# DynamoDB: Using SET on an UpdateExpression to increment a field is not working

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-serverless, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm following the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.IncrementAndDecrement) in order to implement a lambda to increase the value of a field with an scalar value in DynamoDB. In my case I'm using NodeJS SDK v3, but the docs redirect you to [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.IncrementAndDecrement) at some point.

My problem is that the `SET` command in `UpdateExpression` is not working when I use to increase the value of some fields.

This is an example of how I initialize the command and execute it:

```js
const params = {
  TableName: 'MyTable',
  Key: { id: 'my-id' },
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#credit': 'user.credit',
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':creditToAdd': 100,
  },
  UpdateExpression: 'SET #credit = #credit + :creditToAdd',
  ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW'
};

const client = new DynamoDBClient(options);
const docClient = new DynamoDBDocumentClient(client);
const command = new UpdateCommand(params);
const updateUserResponse = await docClient.send(command);
```

And this is the error I get:

```
ValidationException: The provided expression refers to an attribute that does not exist in the item
```

When I use `UpdateExpressions` like this:

```js
UpdateExpression: 'SET #credit = :creditToAdd',
```

I have no problems, only fails when I put some operands on it.

On my tests, I tried to use [`ADD`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.IncrementAndDecrement) instead of `SET`, and it works:

```js
UpdateExpression: 'ADD #credit :creditToAdd',
```

but as you can see in the docs:

> In general, we recommend using SET rather than ADD.

and the true is that I prefer to use it with SET to combine it with the update of other fields, like the timestamp of the date of the last credit addition.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SET` requires that the attribute `user.credit` exists BEFORE the update. In comparison  `ADD` will work on an item that doesn't have the field defined.

Most likely the issue in your test is that field doesn't have an initial value.

Comment: Geez... I think I messed it up while seeding my test table and, right, that attribute has not being defined yet.

Do you recommend me to use `ADD` to ensure it is updated?

Comment: You could use `ADD` which does that implicitly or this Update Expression `SET #views = if_not_exists(#views, :init) + :inc`, you just need the `:init` value to be 0 or whatever your starting position is, [the blog](https://www.tecracer.com/blog/2022/04/implementing-accurate-counters-in-dynamodb-using-python.html) explains this in more detail.